# tar with name pattern in Tcl does not work

Tags: pattern-matching, tcl, exec

When I try to run this command in tcl:

```
tar -zcvf input.scs__pmos.sdevv.tar.gz input.scs*
```

I get this message:

```
/bin/tar: input.scs*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
/bin/tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

child process exited abnormally
while executing
```

However, when I run in Perl/shell I get:

```
perl -e 'system("tar -zcvf input.scs__pmos.sdevv.tar.gz input.scs*")'
```

I get:

```
input.scs
input.scs~
```

Why is Tcl causing this? running from the LINUX Shell yields the same results.
I use Tcl 8.5

Comment: With perl, when you use `system` with a single string, perl will spawn a shell (/bin/sh I think) and send the string to the shell. Then shell is responsible for expanding glob patterns. The Tcl equivalent would be `exec /bin/sh -c "tar -zcvf input.scs__pmos.sdevv.tar.gz input.scs*"`

Answer (score 6):

Tcl does *not* expand filename globs (the `*`) by default. This is by design. If you want that expanded, you must ask for it explicitly (remembering that the expansion produces a *list* of filenames, so we need `{*}[…]` instead of just `[…]`):

```
exec tar -zcvf input.scs__pmos.sdevv.tar.gz {*}[glob input.scs*]
```

It's good style to always add the `exec`; it's only in interactive mode that you can leave that out at all, and that's just a convenience feature. Your scripts *require* it so get in good habits right now.

Comment: If you're still using Tcl 8.4 or before, get with the programme and upgrade. 8.4 has been out of even _security_ support for a few years; no further bugs in it (if there are any) will ever be fixed beyond the 8.4.20 release.